# python pandas: diff by user in a DataFrame containing multiple users

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame containing timestamped events from multiple users.  By default, the DataFrame is sorted by timestamp.

```
uid timestamp other_vars
  1       100        ...
  1       150        ...
  2       150        ...
  2       200        ...
  1       225        ...
  3       300        ...
  3       400        ...
```

I'd like to get the diff of the timestamp *within users*.  That is, for each event, I want to get the time elapsed since the previous event generated by the same user.

```
uid timestamp diff other_vars
  1       100   NA        ...
  1       150   50        ...
  2       150   NA        ...
  2       200   50        ...
  1       225   75        ...
  3       300   NA        ...
  3       400  100        ...
```

Is there a clean way to do this in pandas, ideally without sorting by User?  Thanks!

Comment: `groupby` the `uid` and then `transform`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `groupby`.  I'd `groupby` and then `diff`.  `groupby` will (unsurprisingly) group the rows:

```
>>> df
   uid  timestamp other_vars
0    1        100        ...
1    1        150        ...
2    2        150        ...
3    2        200        ...
4    1        225        ...
5    3        300        ...
6    3        400        ...
>>> for name, gr in df.groupby("uid"):
...     print name
...     print gr
...     
1
   uid  timestamp other_vars
0    1        100        ...
1    1        150        ...
4    1        225        ...
2
   uid  timestamp other_vars
2    2        150        ...
3    2        200        ...
3
   uid  timestamp other_vars
5    3        300        ...
6    3        400        ...
```

And then we select the column we're interested in along these groups and `diff` it:

```
>>> df["diff"] = df.groupby("uid")["timestamp"].diff()
>>> df
   uid  timestamp other_vars  diff
0    1        100        ...   NaN
1    1        150        ...    50
2    2        150        ...   NaN
3    2        200        ...    50
4    1        225        ...    75
5    3        300        ...   NaN
6    3        400        ...   100
```

Note that we didn't sort the timestamps, so if you wanted that you've have to do it explicitly.

Comment: This almost works.  Unfortunately, the Series returned from the grouped diff contains some strange values. Running df["diff"].value_counts() yields "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'".  I can go back and remove these values, but it feels clunky.

Comment: Hmm.  Could you add the output of `df.to_dict()` to your original post?  [Or just a section of it which reproduces your error.]  Either something's weird about your data or there's a bug in your `pandas` version.  Which are you running, by the way?

Comment: I'm running 0.9.1.  Here's a slice of  the to_dict output: ... 7945: 1486.0,
 7946: 85489.0,
 7947: 85763.0,
 7948: array(nan),
 7949: 84609.0,
 7950: 87224.0,
 7951: 85241.0,
 7952: 176535.0,
 7953: 82165.0,
 7954: 87291.0,
 7955: 85195.0,
 7956: 88829.0,
 7957: 72692.0}

Comment: You can see the one array(nan) entry that's tripping up value_counts.

Comment: Yeah, that looks weird.  I don't know how you're getting the `array(nan)` in there in the first place -- it should just be `nan`.

Comment: Still not sure where the arrays come from, but here's the fix: df["diff"][df["diff"].apply(type) == numpy.ndarray] = numpy.NaN